# I get an error about if part in trigger - Oracle

Tags: sql, oracle, plsql, triggers

I have trigger that changes the total number when adding or deleting;

```
CREATE OR REPLACE TRIGGER branch_number_change
AFTER UPDATE ON Branch
FOR EACH ROW
BEGIN
   IF Staff.inserting 
   THEN
     UPDATE branchTotalStaffNumber
     SET branchTotalStaffNumber = branchTotalStaffNumber + 1
     WHERE branchNo = old.branchNo;
   END IF;
   IF Staff.deleting
   THEN 
     UPDATE branchTotalStaffNumber
     SET branchTotalStaffNumber = branchTotalStaffNumber - 1
    WHERE branchNo = old.branchNo;
   END IF;
END;
```

When I run the sql command it gives a lot of errors and doesn't add the second `end if` part to the trigger. Where is the problem?

Here are the errors;

> Error starting at line : 65 in command -
> UPDATE branchTotalStaffNumber
> SET branchTotalStaffNumber = branchTotalStaffNumber - 1
> WHERE branchNo = old.branchNo
> Error at Command Line : 65 Column : 13
> Error report - SQL Error: ORA-00942: tablo veya görüntü mevcut
> degil
> 00000 -  "table or view does not exist"
> *Cause:
> *Action:
> Error starting at line : 68 in command -    END IF Error report -
> Unknown Command

I would be glad if you help!!

Comment: Welcome to SO! "Lots of errors" doesn't help us much, post actual error messages please.

Comment: I added the actual error

Comment: This looks suspiciously like the problem just posted by 'zeynep', at https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65187312/is-there-any-way-to-create-this-trigger-or-should-i-use-something-else.   Are you in the same course, working the same homework problem?  I'd echo the response he got (mathguy beat me to it there).  You should not be storing 'totalstaffnumber' at all. Basic rule, do not store that which can easily be calculated at run time.  I've been in this business almost 40 years and can assure you that if you do this, the stored value _will_ get out of sync with reality.

Comment: @EdStevens It is possible that we are in the same course obviously. Thank you for answer!

Comment: Whenever I see two posts about the same query, my first thought is "these two guys are in the same class working on the same homework issue, and my second thought is "so why are they not talking to/helping each other?"

Comment: @EdStevens because i didn't know until you're mention it, 
obviously we are not friends with her

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your code contains basic syntax errors.

1. The conditional predicates stand alone without prefixes: INSERTING, DELETING
2. The namespaces take a colon: :OLD, :NEW
3. There is no :OLD namespace when the action is an insert
4. Your trigger checks for INSERTING or DELETING but only fires on UPDATE

Your trigger should look like this:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE TRIGGER branch_number_change
AFTER INSERT OR UPDATE OR DELETE ON Branch
FOR EACH ROW
BEGIN
   IF inserting 
   THEN
     UPDATE branchTotalStaffNumber
     SET branchTotalStaffNumber = branchTotalStaffNumber + 1
     WHERE branchNo = :new.branchNo;
   END IF;
   IF deleting
   THEN 
     UPDATE branchTotalStaffNumber
     SET branchTotalStaffNumber = branchTotalStaffNumber - 1
     WHERE branchNo = :old.branchNo;
   END IF;
END;
```

The Oracle PL/SQL Reference has copious examples of correct syntax. You can easily answer future questions by comparing your code with things in the documentation. I suggest you [bookmark it for future reference](https://docs.oracle.com/database/121/LNPLS/triggers.htm#LNPLS20041).

---

There does seems to be a problem with the logic of your trigger. It is incrementing a total whose name suggests it is maintaining a count of **staff members**. But the trigger is on the BRANCH table rather than a STAFF or EMPLOYEE table. Also you're updating a column `branchTotalStaffNumber` which has the same name as the table: is that correct? Could that explain why you get that ORA-00942 error?

Given that, maybe your trigger should be on STAFF like this:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE TRIGGER staff_number_change
AFTER INSERT OR UPDATE OR DELETE ON Staff
FOR EACH ROW
BEGIN
   IF inserting 
   THEN
     UPDATE branch
     SET branchTotalStaffNumber = branchTotalStaffNumber + 1
     WHERE branchNo = :new.branchNo;
   END IF;
   IF deleting
   THEN 
     UPDATE branch
     SET branchTotalStaffNumber = branchTotalStaffNumber - 1
     WHERE branchNo = :old.branchNo;
   END IF;

   IF updating 
   and :new.branchNo != :old.branchNo
   THEN
     UPDATE branch
     SET branchTotalStaffNumber = branchTotalStaffNumber + 1
     WHERE branchNo = :new.branchNo;
     UPDATE branch
     SET branchTotalStaffNumber = branchTotalStaffNumber - 1
     WHERE branchNo = :old.branchNo;
   END IF;
END;
```

Comment: wow I understood very well thank you very much!! :)

Comment: By the way, I got the ORA-00942 error for the reason you said, I understood when you said.

Answer (score 1):

See my comment regarding the wisdom of this exercise.  As for the actual error code, either:

1. Given that you are not qualifying the table names with their owner (ie: 'UPDATE branchTotalStaffNumber' vs. 'UPDATE owner.branchTotalStaffNumber') my guess is that the user issuing the command is not the owner of the table. or
2. the specified table does not exist (as the error says) or
3. the user issuing the command does not have the necessary privs.